# Make a new folder based on cell name and copy list of file into it

Tags: excel, vba, directory, copy

I am new in the VBA excel.
I would like to ask to everyone.

I have a list of document with .pdf extension (in column A1:A20). I want to copy all documents from source folder (in my disk C:) to destination folder (in disk D:). The destination folder is a new folder that named by cell value (B1 on other sheet).

```
'This code for copy files from the document list
 Sub copyfiles()

 Const sourcePath As String = "C:\Users\"  'source folder
 Const DestPath As String = "D:\Users\" 'how to change it with new folder that named is from cell B1 'destination folder
 Const ListAddress As String = "A1:A20"  'document list

' Write file list to array.
 Dim FileList As Variant: FileList = Sheet4.Range(ListAddress).Value

' 'Get' first file name.
 Dim FName As String: FName = Dir(sourcePath)
' 'Initiate' counter.
Dim i As Long
' Loop files in SourcePath.
Do While FName <> ""
' Check if file name of current file is contained in array (FileList).
If Not IsError(Application.Match(FName, FileList, 0)) Then
    ' Count file.
    i = i + 1
    ' Copy file.
    FileCopy sourcePath & FName, DestPath & FName
End If
' 'Get' next file name.
FName = Dir()
Loop

' Inform user.
Select Case i
Case 0: MsgBox "No files found", vbExclamation, "No Files"
Case 1: MsgBox "Copied 1 file.", vbInformation, "Success"
Case Else: MsgBox "Copied " & i & " files.", vbInformation, "Success"
End Select
End Sub
```

I try to make new folder based on cell value with this code, but I have no idea how to connect it with destination folder.

```
Dim startPath As String
Dim myName As String
startPath = "H:\Users\"
myName = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Cover Page").Range("B1").Text      
If myName = vbNullString Then myName = "Nuovo"
Dim folderPathWithName As String
folderPathWithName = startPath & Application.PathSeparator & myName
If Dir(folderPathWithName, vbDirectory) = vbNullString Then
MkDir folderPathWithName
Else
MsgBox "Folder already exists"
Exit Sub
End
```

Is there anyone here can help me with the code to connect it?
Thanks in advance for every help.

For you who read this thread and maybe have same problem, I already solved this problem. I change this code:

```
 Const sourcePath As String = "C:\Users\"  'source folder
 Const DestPath As String = "D:\Users\" 'how to change it with new folder that named is from cell B1 'destination folder
 Const ListAddress As String = "A1:A20"  'document list
```

With this code

```
 sourcePath = "C:\Users\"  'source folder
 DestPath = "D:\Users\" ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Cover Page").Range("B1").Value  'This is the destination folder with the name from cell B1, sheet "Front Page"
 ListAddress = "A1:A20"  'document list

 On Error Resume Next
 MkDir (DestPath)     'To create the destination folder
```

Comment: What have you tried to achieve this? Also, showing screen shot of your sheets would really help. Might be worth reading [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Comment: When you say _ Anyone can help me with that?_ what are you actually asking?  Are you asking for some general guidance,  or are you asking for someone to write the code for you?

Comment: hi all, thank you for the responses. I ask if there is someone who can help me with the code. I have already now how to copy the list of file, but have no idea how to create new folder that named based on cell value and set it as destination folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something as below:

```
DestPath = "D:\" & Cells(i, 2).Value & "\"
On Error Resume Next
MkDir (DestPath)
FileCopy sourcePath & FName, DestPath & FName
```

Comment: I have assumed that you have the folder name in Column B in the excel sheet